# Are writes to BTreeMaps expensive? How much compute units does it take?

Tags: anchor, compute-budget

I am using a quite a few BTreeMaps and i am writing to 2 BTreeMaps and it is using all the compute units. So i wanted to know how much compute units it takes and what can be the alternatives for using a map with much less compute units.

Also is there a way of increasing compute units? I am ready to pay extra tx fees if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "write" as not all writes are equal.

For example, it will be expensive if you grow the `BTreeMap` inside a loop but it won't be expensive if you mutate one of it's values.

You can increase the compute units limit of the transaction by including a [`ComputeBudgetInstruction.SetComputeUnitLimit`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/09e858d93971ccc768080fd5b658ecb7c8570908/sdk/src/compute_budget.rs#L40) instruction in your transaction.

Example:

```
import { ComputeBudgetProgram, Transaction } from "@solana/web3.js";

const computeUnitIx = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ 
  units: 1_000_000
});

const tx = new Transaction()
  .add(computeUnitIx)
  .add(/* Your instruction... */);
```

[Solana Cookbook link](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-fee-priority-for-a-transaction)

Comment: is there a table where i can refer how the compute units are calculated and what they depend on? I would also love to know some things which can normally increase the compute units like loops.